# ASCII files in R

Tags: r, ascii

I have some data that's in an ASCII format. I'm not allowed to put the data online so unfortunately I can't post it on here (although I realize that it would be the most helpful that way). The code I'm using now to get the ASCII data in R is...

```
library(SAScii)
parse.SAScii("file.txt")
```

But then I get this error:

```
Error in firstline:lastline : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning message:
In min(a[a > firstline]) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

I can't find anything online about this error and I was hoping someone might be able to point me to what I could be doing wrong. I know this question is kind of vague but I'm just hoping someone can direct me in the right direction.

Comment: You could produce example data, that mimics the data and therefor provide an verifiable example.

Comment: SAScii is designed for SAS files. What is wrong with `read.table` or `readLines`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to read lines from a file with that name in the working directory:

```
my.input <- readLines("file.txt")
head(my.input)
str(my.input)
```